# SalesForce SOAPUI Login call fails with SocketTimeoutException

Tags: salesforce, soapui, salesforce-communities

I am new to SalesForce and trying to setup my first call to Sandbox SalesForce.
I generated a Enterprise WSDL file and created the project in SOAPUI.

The login request has URL set to https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/48.0/0DFr0000XXXXXXX

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login>
         <urn:username>XXXX@XXXXXXX</urn:username>
         <urn:password>Password+Token</urn:password>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException

I am able to put this URL in browser and get a response

https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/48.0/0DFr0000XXXXXXX

and get response

```
Only POST allowed
```

That means it might not be firewall issue??
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

(not 100% an answer but too long for a comment)

1. It might be that you're behind a proxy or firewall. Maybe your browser automatically downloads some configuration script but in SoapUI and other tools like that you'd need to specify the proxy details manually. Do you have any other app that can connect OK? Data Loader? maybe simple `ping test.salesforce.com`? `curl` if you're familiar with it? Or tell SoapUI to GET www.google.com and see what happens? If these fail - talk with your IT about proxy details. Or try from another machine?
2. See if anything hit Salesforce. Go to your user in setup, scroll all the way down to login history, see if there's any non-browser activity.
3. It's possible your SF admin disabled logging in from generic test.salesforce.com. You can verify it in Setup -> My Domain. (but if you can login via browser just fine and it's with normal SF username and pass, no Single Sign-On tricks - ignore this point)
4. As stupid as it sounds - what's the timeout you have in SoapUI ;)